# MakeFeatureLayer throwing error 00840: The value is not a feature layer

Tags: arcpy, error-000840

I'm working through tutorials from the book "GIS Tutorial for Python Scripting," by David W. Allen, and I have this code pretty much exactly the way the book wants it (I altered one variable name from LayerSStations to LayerStation because the double-S was giving me problems seeing it) and every time I run it it throws the error "00840: The value is not a feature layer."

Here's my code, up to the point it throws the error:

```
import arcpy

#create a map document object for the map document
thisMap = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\Andy\Documents\GIS DataBase\EsriPress\GISTPython\Maps\Tutorial 3-3.mxd")

#Create data frame object
myDF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(thisMap)[0]

#Create list object of the map elements
myMapElements = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(thisMap)

#Get a list of all layers in the table of contents
#Use a for loop to find layers Parcels and SamplingStations
#assign them to new variables for easier reference
myLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(myDF)

for lyr in myLayers:
    if lyr.name == "Parcels":
        print "Parcels have been found."
        layerParcels = lyr
    elif lyr.name == "SamplingStations":
        print "Sampling Stations have been found."
        layerStation = lyr

#create feature layer to hold only Operational sampling stations 
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(layerStation,"ActiveStations_lyr",'"Status=\'Operational\'')
```

It's failing on that last command, the MakeFeatureLayer_management line. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I've been over and over the variable names looking for wrong things, I have done Rubber Duck debugging, and I can't nail down the problem.

EDIT: Added more of the original code to the snippet.

Comment: Firstly you have one missing double quotation mark in `'"Status=\'Operational\''` after Status. If this does not help, what does it say once you type in `print layerStation` and/or `print type(layerStation)`?

Comment: When you present us with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code snippet, which I thank you for trying to do, I think for code like this you should also include the lines that create your MapDocument and DataFrame objects.  Otherwise, it is not Complete.  Also, depending on what else you are trying to do, you may find that using your SQL expression to set lyr.definitionQuery, instead of using MakeFeatureLayer, is more flexible and less code.

Comment: @fatih_dur Thanks for noticing the missing double quote, but adding it doesn't fix anything - neither does removing the SQL statement entirely.
I added the print statements you suggested. `print layerStations` yields `SamplingStations` and `print type(layerStations)` yields `<class arcpy._mapping.Layer>`

Comment: Works fine for me. I'd suggest just restarting ArcMap, and trying again. Are you sure there's not a space between Sampling Stations, or something simple like that?

Comment: @ian I found it - the map document hadn't saved properly when I'd pointed at the correct workspace for the data. When I got out a clean copy of the file and pointed it at the right data, the script worked. Now onto the next 20 typoes and problems. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your code. if your code goes into this if statement:

```
if lyr.name == "Parcels":
```

then the layerStation will be None (it will not be assigned). Therefore, MakeFeatureLayer will throw an error. the proper code would be:

```
for lyr in myLayers:
    if lyr.name == "Parcels":
        print "Parcels have been found."
        finalLayer = lyr
    elif lyr.name == "SamplingStations":
        print "Sampling Stations have been found."
        finalLayer = lyr

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(finalLayer,"ActiveStations_lyr",'"Status=\'Operational\'')
```

Comment: You cannot know this as highlighted by @Polygeo without seeing the code context. In the map document there could be these two layers (which I think this is the case) and OP is trying to create **a new layer** by applying an SQL statement to one of them.

Comment: @fatih_dur has the right of it - the for loop is supposed to go through and create layer objects for **both** Parcels and SamplingStations. From what I can tell with some print statements I inserted - `print layerStations` and `print type(layerStations)` both layers are being created and persist after the for loop as type `<class 'arcpy._mapping.Layer'>`.
I've added the rest of the code to the OP.